# background image size responzive design

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive design for my site.

I have a display logo like this:

```
<h1><a href="http://example.com/">example.com</a></h1>
```

and I show the logo in CSS:

```
#header h1{
margin-top:23px;
background: url(http://www.example.com/files/logo.jpg) no-repeat !important;
float: left;
text-indent: -9999px
```

}

I have now created a new CSS file for mobile visitors and responsive design.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { ...
```

How do I achieve that the logo is re-sized according to width of user's phone/browser? I discovered background-size property but haven't succeeded in using it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
header h1 { 
  background: url(http://www.example.com/files/logo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```